# Why is DNStwist showing a domain available but online check shows taken?

Tags: dns, internet, website, domain-name

For example, when using the software DNStwist to enumerate domain name "dege.com", it shows "degee.com" available, but when using several web domain availability sites, those sites say "degee.com" taken. Anyone know why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, not sure where yoy looked since you didn't include a link or screenshot, but on https://dnstwist.it/ it shows `degee.com` in use:
[image]

But regardless, this ***dnstwist*** isn't intended to be, and isn't, a check if a domain is **Registered** or ***Available***, all it does is scan the domain if there is something live connected to it (=if the DNS resolves to something.) But someone can own a domain (=have a domain registered) and not use it for anything (yet or ever.)